# A sequence of distributions converges to a certain distribution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Given the sequence of functions:

\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=tanh(nx)
\end{equation}

and knowing that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, & x<0 \\
1, & x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

prove that the correspoding sequence of distributions: 
\begin{equation}
\langle T_{f_n},\phi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_n(x)\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
converges to the distribution:
\begin{equation}
\langle T_f,\phi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
In fact, all I want to prove is that:
\begin{equation}
|\langle T_{f_n},\phi\rangle-\langle T_f,\phi\rangle|\to 0
\end{equation}
But when I reach a point where:
\begin{equation}
\langle T_{f_n},\phi\rangle-\langle T_f,\phi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(tanh(nx)+1)\phi(x)dx+\int_{0}^{+\infty}(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
, then I have no idea how to proceed. Can someone help? Thanks!

***UPDATE:
In order to prove that the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)dx \to 0
\end{equation}
I must show the following:

1) The sequence: $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f$, $\forall \phi \in D{\mathbb{(R)}}$.

2)The functions $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are Riemann integrable.

I would like your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
We have an odd function here:
$$\tanh -x = -\tanh x$$
This gives rise to
$$\int_0^\infty (\tanh nx - 1)\phi(x) - (\tanh nx - 1)\phi(-x)\ \mathrm dx = \int_0^\infty (\tanh nx - 1)(\phi(x) - \phi(-x))\ \mathrm dx$$
The second factor is another testing function, so all you need to do is show that
$$\int_0^\infty \tanh nx - 1 \ \mathrm dx \to 0$$

Comment: Yeap, I tried also to set $x\to -x$, but why would this assist me?

Comment: @Mitscaype I expanded a bit.

Comment: Can you please provide the step where the integrals merge? That is what is actually my critical point. After that, it is quite clear thank you for your assistance!

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^0 (\tanh nx + 1)\phi(x)\ \mathrm dx \stackrel{x\mapsto -x}= -\int_\infty^0 (\tanh -nx + 1)\phi(-x) = \int_0^\infty -(\tanh nx - 1)\phi(-x)\ \mathrm dx$$
Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you both AlexR and @Ian for your answers! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$|\tanh(x)-1|=\left | \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}-1 \right |=\left | \frac{e^x-e^{-x}-e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}} \right | \leq e^{-x}$$

The situation is exactly the same on the other side, since $\tanh$ is odd.